# In app purchases finishTransaction

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I am able to make a full purchase in my app. However when the purchase is done, nothing is happening, the content in not unlock.
When I click again it tells me "*You've already purchased this In-App Purchase but it hasn't been downloaded*".
So, from Apple documentation the problem is the **finishTransaction:** isn't called.

Edit2: Full code, thank you again for help

```
class PurchaseController: UIViewController, SKPaymentTransactionObserver, SKProductsRequestDelegate {

var product: SKProduct = SKProduct()
var productID: NSString = NSString()
var homeViewController: GameScene!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}


func getProductInfo(viewController: GameScene) {
    homeViewController = viewController

    let object: NSSet! = NSSet(object: self.productID)

    if (SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()) {
        let request: SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: object)
        request.delegate = self
        request.start()
    }
    else {
        println("please enbale in app purchase")
    }
}


func productsRequest(request: SKProductsRequest!, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse!) {
    var products: NSArray = response.products

    if (products.count != 0) {
        product = products[0] as SKProduct
        let payment: SKPayment = SKPayment(product: product)
        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(payment)
    }

    products = response.invalidProductIdentifiers
    for product in products {
        println("Product not found : \(product)")
    }
}


func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, updatedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!) {
    let transaction: SKPaymentTransaction = SKPaymentTransaction()
    let transactionPurchased: SKPaymentTransactionState = SKPaymentTransactionState.Purchased
    let transactionFailed: SKPaymentTransactionState = SKPaymentTransactionState.Failed

    for transaction in transactions {
        switch transaction.transactionState  {

        case transactionPurchased:
            self.unlockFeature()
            println("transaction OK")
            queue.finishTransaction(transaction as SKPaymentTransaction)
        case transactionFailed:
            println("Transaction failed")
            queue.finishTransaction(transaction as SKPaymentTransaction)
        default:
            println("Transaction problem")
        }
    }
}
```

In my other class:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

   var purchaseController: PurchaseController!

   //Other code...

   override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
      purchaseController = PurchaseController()
      let defaultQueue: SKPaymentQueue = SKPaymentQueue()
      defaultQueue.addTransactionObserver(purchaseController)
   }

   // On a button click
   if (nodeAtPoint(location).name == "removeAdLabel") {
      purchaseController.productID = "com.appsforyou.rvads"
      purchaseController.getProductInfo(self)  
   }
}
```

With a breakpoint, the add payment to the transaction queue works but then the paymentQueue:updatedTransactions: seems to not be called

Comment: You say none of the printlns execute. Have you set a breakpoint and confirmed that the observer method is even called?  Where is the code that sets this class as the observer?

Comment: when I set breakpoint, I can see the prinln "Transaction OK" and the function unlockFeature working, but it happen at the launch of app and without pressing the buy button

Comment: That is possible.  Transactions that aren't finalised will be re-presented when your app launches- it may be that the user exited your app or connectivity was lost during the purchase process, so Apple will continue to re-present the transaction until it is finalised.  The question, then, seems to be why isn't this method called when you initially perform the purchase.  Perhaps checking/showing that code could help